# How to integrate simplecov with a Ruby gem using RSpec (no rails)?

Tags: ruby, rspec, simplecov

When adding simplecov to a rails project using RSpec, I'd place this at the very top of rails_helper.rb

```
require 'simplecov'

SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  add_filter '/spec/'     

  add_group 'Controllers', 'app/controllers'
  add_group 'Models', 'app/models'
end
```

What is the expected location and code needed to have simplecov document the code coverage of a vanilla ruby gem?

Comment: It would be exactly the same just without the `'rails'` portion. Add this to `spec_helper.rb`. eg. (`require 'simplecov';SimpleCov.start { add_filter '/spec/'; add_group 'SomeGroup','somelib/directory';}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the gem in gemspec

```
s.add_development_dependency "simplecov"
```

Then at the very top of `spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'simplecov'

SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter '/spec/' 
end
```

This should cover the relevant `/lib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

As engineersmnky mentioned, the code is pretty much the same regardless of the framework.

Include the SimpleCov start at the top of your spec helper before you require any files.